# Write a file in SDcard in Android

Tags: java, android

I have been searching this problem.
It actually worked in older version of android, but after I updated SDK, I get an error.
Error message is "open filed: ENOTDIR (Not a directory): /sdcard/PlayNumbers/mysdfile.xml"
Can please someone point me what I did wrong??
My codes are below.

Many Thanks,

```
path=new File("/sdcard/PlayNumbers");
myFile = new File(path,"mysdfile.xml");
if (!path.exists()) {
    path.mkdirs();
}
if(!myFile.exists()){
    myFile.createNewFile();
}

FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

myOutWriter.append("test");
myOutWriter.close();
fOut.close();
```

==>

```
File path = null;
File myFile = null;
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
path=new File(filePath+"/PlayNumbers/");
myFile = new File(path,"mysdfile.xml");

//i also tried both as below
//path=new File(filePath+"/PlayNumbers");
//myFile = new File(path,"mysdfile.xml");

if (!path.exists()) {
    path.mkdirs();
}
if(!myFile.exists()){
    myFile.createNewFile();
}
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
myOutWriter.append("test");
myOutWriter.close();
fOut.close();
```

p.s. ok, I have changed as you guys mentioned like my code, but it still gives me same error that it is not directory... any idea???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to change to the following code  because you missing "/":

```
myFile = new File(path,"/mysdfile.xml");
```

But keep in mind that you have to have the permission for writing in external storage in your manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Hello Husam A. Al-ahmadi, I have tried but it still gives ENOTDIR error (mnt/sdcard/PlayNumbers/mysdfile.xml). Also, I have the external_storage permission.

Comment: OK JMax, I have "/". i wrote as path=new File(filePath+"/PlayNumbers");.. im still getting error. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 3):

This should work, assuming that you have the correct permission in your manifest:

```
File externalStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File playNumbersDir = new File(externalStorageDir, "PlayNumbers");
File myFile = new File(playNumbersDir, "mysdfile.xml");

if (!playNumbersDir.exists()) {
    playNumbersDir.mkdirs();
}
if(!myFile.exists()){
    myFile.createNewFile();
}
```